# videoTileWasRemoved() not being called after stopVideoInput() is called

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

When I call stopVideoInput() by clicking a button, on my side the video stops, but on the remote side the video just freezes instead of turning off completely. Using Chime SDK v3.

```
 videoTileDidUpdate(tileState: VideoTileState): void {
        const videoElementId = tileState.localTile ? "local-video" : "remote-video";
        const videoElement: HTMLVideoElement = this.domElement(videoElementId);
    
 

      if (videoElement) {
              console.info("binding video element: " + videoElementId);
              this._audioVideo.bindVideoElement(tileState.tileId, videoElement);
            } else {
              console.error(videoElementId + " video not found");
            }
          }
        
    
          videoTileWasRemoved(tileId: number) {
            console.log("videoTileWasRemoved...");
            this._audioVideo.unbindVideoElement(tileId);
          }
```

stopVideoInput is called here

```
          endCamera(): void {
            this.av.stopVideoInput();
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call stopVideoInput, only videoTileDidUpdate will get called with the inactive tile state. Chime SDK is reusing the same local tile object when you restart it by calling startLocalVideoTile.

```
videoTileDidUpdate: tileState => {
   if (tileState.localTile) {
     // tileState.active will be false when you call stopLocalVideoTile
   }
}
```

videoTileWasRemoved gets invoked when you call removeLocalVideoTile. Chime SDK will remove the local video tile. Please review the "Stop sharing your video" example in: [AWS Chime SDK - Video](https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-js#video)

Source: [AWS Chime SKD GitHub](https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-js/issues/298)